# Pandas KeyError when using dates in column name

Tags: python, pandas

DataFrame:

```
year_month  nr_kunde    2020-06-01  2020-07-01  2020-08-01  2020-09-01  2020-10-01  2020-11-01  2020-12-01  2021-01-01  2021-02-01  2021-03-01  2021-04-01  2021-05-01
0   1234523231232312    4739.0000   3793.0000   3817.0000   4682.3333   4853.0000   5005.0000   4992.0000   4857.0000   4867.0000   4800.0000   4875.0000   4801.0000
1   2312321312312332    7126.0000   7118.0000   7118.6667   7519.8333   7600.0000   7646.0000   7323.0000   7353.0000   7381.0000   7312.0000   7261.0000   7264.0000
```

I try to convert columns to a float type, with this code:

```
for col in pandas_df.columns:
    try:
        pandas_df[col] = pandas_df[col].as_type(float)
    except:
        print(f'Not able to convert {col} to float')

Not able to convert 2020-06-01 to float
Not able to convert 2020-07-01 to float
Not able to convert 2020-08-01 to float
Not able to convert 2020-09-01 to float
```

This `pandas_df["2020-06-01"]` will result in a keyerror: `KeyError: '2020-06-01'`

I assume this is due to the numbers in the column names, but I need the date in as column name: So my question is: How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post a sample please? `pandas_df.head()` and  the output of `df.columns`

Comment: `pandas_df["2020-06-01"]` works perfectly.

Comment: for me is does not, still get the keyerror. May it be related to the pandas version?

Comment: I used `pandas_df = pandas_df.rename(columns=lambda x: "D" + str(x))` to fix it, not perfect but better than nothing. Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dt2sec = pd.to_datetime(pandas_df.columns[2:]).strftime('%s')
pandas_df.columns = pandas_df.columns[:2].append(dt2sec)
```

```
>>> pandas_df['1590962400']
0    4739.0
1    7126.0
Name: 1590962400, dtype: float64
```